# Default action on input field in Android WebView

Tags: android, forms, input, webview

I'm displaying a standard `<form>` with a few `<input>` fields in a web view.
When editing the first input field and pressing the enter key on the soft keyboard, the form is posted insted of focusing the next input field in the form.

How can I stop the form from being posted and instead put focus on the next input field?

Edit:
Problem solved by adding a piece of javascript to the page;

```
<body onkeypress='return event.keyCode!=13; '>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to wire up an "OnClick" event in your Java file - I don't think it's possible. The "WebView" control just displays CSS/HTML/JS (i.e. web pages).

You should be able to use a javascript snippet to accomplish this though. Something along these lines:

```
<html>
    <body onkeydown='if (event.keyCode==13) {event.keyCode=9; return event.keyCode }'>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. Your code did not prevent the form from being posted, but just a few minor changes solved the problem. Returning false on key==13 did the trick. <body onkeypress='return event.keyCode!=13; '>